# how to create setup for j2ee web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, browser, installation

I have done my j2ee(MVC)web application(client server).

I want to give my application to clients as setup (like mozila firefox setup).

Once clients installed my setup then there should be create my application shortcut.

whenever clients open my application shortcut that should access the server(like mozila firefox setup).

I know that i cant create setup using eclipse.so how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're mixing topics here, because the idea of a web app is that you can access to a web app in a page and win, no need to install anything besides your browser.
The installation of a server does not make sense, because a web server could need DB access and other very fine configurations, but if you application is simple, or if the installation is a requerimient for your software, then all you need to do is:
- Prepare the server with the app loaded.
- Create the scripts for run or stop the server (.bat in windows, .sh in linux).
- Compress the scripts and the server.
- Create a setup tool (there are many out there), you don't need advanced features, just copy and paste your files in a installation folder, and make sure you create an access to the start and stop scripts.
- Now all you need is that the user click in your start script and voala!, he can access to the app.
You can add the sripts as a service to allow the server run automatically in every startup.